# How to deserialize an Xml String into an object that has properties with private setters?

Tags: c#, xml, xml-serialization

I am receiving an Xml String over a network and I want to be able to put the contents of it within an object. When I keep the setters of the class as public, it works totally fine. However, I want to be able to keep them private, in which case I get the following error:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'Cannot deserialize type 'MyApp.Random' because it contains property 'data' which has no public setter.'

I have looked all over the internet and haven't found a solution.

My class is very simple, like this:

```
public class Random
{
    public string data{ get;  private set; }

    public string abc{ get;  private set; }

    public string defg{ get;  private set; }
}
```

This is how I'm trying to deserialize it:

```
var serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(Random));

result = (Random)serializer.Deserialize(new StringReader(xmlString));
```

Comment: I have already read a lot of threads mentioning that the xml serializer simply DOES require public setters, but I was wondering if there is a way to circumvent this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fixed it. I just used the DataContractSerializer instead of the XmlSerializer and it worked like a charm. Here is the solution:

```
var ser = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(Random));
Random result = (Random)ser.ReadObject(new MemoryStream(xmlString));
```